# In github is there a way to prevent pull requests to main from any other branch but dev?

Tags: github

I am trying to define the following rule: "allow pull requests to `main` only from `dev`"; so if someone opens a PR from a random branch to `main` it should not be allowed. How do I go on doing that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a GitHub workflow to your project that will run on every opened pull request. In that workflow you can compare the source and target branch and throw an error if it's not meet your requirements. The workflow can be something like this.

```yaml
name: Check pull request source branch
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
jobs:
  check-branches:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check branches
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.head_ref }} != "dev" ] && [ ${{ github.base_ref }} == "main" ]; then
            echo "Merge requests to main branch are only allowed from dev branch."
            exit 1
          fi
```

When you have the workflow, go to your project settings, click on **Branches** and then click **Add rule**. Mark the checkbox of **Require status checks to pass before merging** and select the status check **check-branches** from the drop down menu. Then click on save. If you now try to merge a pull request with **main** as the target branch and any other branch except of **dev** as the source branch, the workflow will throw an error and your are not able to merge.

Answer (score 6):

Just a note that you should also add 'edited' to the types above so that the check runs again when someone who created the PR with the base branch set to `main` changes it to `dev` after the PR has already been created and after they see the failing check. Otherwise they'd have to close and reopen the PR to trigger it again.

I've added to Sascha's solution so this would be better:

```yaml
name: Check pull request source branch
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
      - edited
jobs:
  check-branches:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check branches
        run: |
          if [ ${{ github.head_ref }} != "dev" ] && [ ${{ github.base_ref }} == "main" ]; then
            echo "Merge requests to main branch are only allowed from dev branch."
            exit 1
          fi
```